# stuck in contraints in a easy exercise

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to solve this exercise, It seems easy [this](http://wcipeg.com/problem/ccc10j1), but I can not understand the contraints -rules, It says:

1. the number may be represented on one or two hands;
2. **if the number is represented on two hands, the larger number is given first**

   The rule number 2 I can not understand for example if it says 3, I have 3, 2+1, 1+2 (this not because its repeated),  if it says 6 we have 6, 5+1, 4+2, 3+3, 2+4 + 1+5 but the correct output is 3, can someone guide me in this problem??   for 7 is 2, and 8 is 2, 9  is 1, and 10 is 1.

this is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class j1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int tot = 5;
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= tot; i++) {

            for (int j = 1; j <= tot; j++) {
                sum = i + j;
                if (sum == n) {

                    System.out.println(i);
                    System.out.println(j);
                    count++;
                }
              }


        }

        System.out.println(count);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The larger number is given first. That means that 1+2 is invalid, as are also 2+4 and 1+5. Also, 6 is invalid because we are presumably talking non-mutated, normal human hands (range 0..5)! Therefore there are 3 ways to express "6": 5+1, 4+2, 3+3

Comment: The statement of the problem sounds ambiguous.  For the example `6`, any of the answers `5+1`, `4+2`, and `3+3` satisfies requirement 2, so unless there's another requirement specifying that the subcomponents must be as close to equal as possible, it's not clear why only `3+3` is correct.

Comment: @JimGarrison The problem asks for the number of correct solutions. The correct output is 3 because `5+1`, `4+2`, and `3+3` are the 3 solutions.

Comment: Ah, that was missing from the problem statement.

Comment: @lc. If I have 7? the answer says 2

Comment: @koyuki of course, `5+2` and `4+3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple - if you are going to give the number using both the hands (2 hands) then you will first need to give the larger number which comprises the overall number -

eg for 7 (4+3 OR 5+2) when represented using 2 hands - give 4 first !

other option for 7 (3+4, 2+5) are invalid since it will make us to list the smaller number first which violates the rule #2

Comment: Why wouldn't 5+2 be counted first?  5 > 4.

Answer (score 1):

The number of the second hand must always be less than or equal to the number of the first hand. I believe the code below will work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class j1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int tot = 5;
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= tot; i++) {

            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                sum = i + j;
                if (sum == n) {

                    System.out.println(i);
                    System.out.println(j);
                    count++;
                }
              }


        }

        System.out.println(count);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I'm not seeing any difference with the code sample either.

Comment: There's one difference: the condition of the inner loop - `j <= i` where the question has `j <= tot`.

Comment: Fair enough; go ahead and edit your answer a bit (clean it up with using some unique variable names) so I could change my vote.